# Is there a unique minimizing geodesic to a geodesically convex set?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic, convex-geometry

Let $(\mathcal M,g)$ be a geodesically complete Riemannian manifold, and $\mathcal X\subset \mathcal M$ be a compact, geodesically convex subset.

It is trivial that for any point $x\in\mathcal M$, there exists a unique $y\in\mathcal X$ minimizing $d(x,y)$.

But is there a unique geodesic of minimal length from $x$ to $y$ in $\mathcal M$?

Comment: Could you provide definitions of geodesically complete Riemannian manifold and geodesically convex subset? Assuming the surface of a sphere belong to such sets, if $x$ and $y$ are two antipodal points, then the minimal geodesics are not unique.

Comment: thanks! that's a valid counter-example

Comment: It's not necessarily true that the closest point to $x$ in $\mathcal X$ is unique. For example, let $\mathcal M$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^3$ with its standard metric, let $\mathcal X$ be a small closed arc on the equator (of length less than $\pi$), and let $x$ be the north pole. Then $\mathcal X$ is compact and geodesically convex, but every point of $\mathcal X$ is the same distance from $x$.

Answer (score 0):

No.

In $\mathbb{S}^n$, take a small closed ball (i.e. south of the equator) centered at the south pole.  There is no unique $y$ that minimizes the distance from the north pole (the whole boundary is a constant latitude circle and hence every point there minimizes $d(N,-)$).